# Arithmetic derivative perfect number

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers, arithmetic-derivative

Is there another perfect number $n$ besides 6 such that $n'<n$, where $n'$ is the arithmetic derivative?

Comment: What is the definition of the arithmetic derivative?

Comment: sorry cant add the definition at the moment

Comment: Have you even tried checking any examples? $28$ satisfies this too.

Comment: I hadn't thank you

Comment: actually the arithmetic derivative of 28 is 32 so it does not meet the criteria

Comment: @argamon:  I added the **perfect-numbers** tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$6$ is the only such **even** number.

The only even perfect numbers are $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ where $2^p-1$ is prime.

Suppose $p\ge3$, the derivative is then $(p-1)2^{p-2}(2^p-1)+2^{p-1}$ and this is greater than $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$.

Comment: that is exactly what I was guessing but  was too foggy to see the proof ...thank you

Comment: You are very welcome.